# Tree, Combination Forest and Tikz Packages for Alignment and sister distance per node

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, alignment

I've tried to create a tree diagram and I know exactly what I want to achieve (it seems basic), but it is not going too well. When using the tikz package, I did achieve the result I wanted, however, the second level nodes were not in the same alignment. After looking at people who had the same issue, I tried the forest package, which did create clear alignments per level (just like i wanted to). However, within the forest package, it seems the sister distance is not changeable per level, which I would prefer.

Basically, I want the result to look like the first tree diagram I included, but on the same level alignments as the second so that the 'non western' and 'western' nodes are exactly on the same vertical alignment. How do I fix this? Is there a way to combine the two codes into the result I want to achieve?

[image]

The codes of both diagrams are:

```
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\newlength\treeheight
\footnotesize
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=right,
  anchor=west,
  growth parent anchor=east, 
  parent anchor=east, 
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.8cm, level distance=1cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm, level distance=1cm}]
  \node {Total sample}[edge from parent fork right]
    child {node {Native}}
        child { node {First-generation}
      child{ node {Non-Western}
        child{ node {Turkey}}
        child{ node {Morocco}}
        child{ node {Surinam}}
     child{ node {Netherlands Antilles}}
        child{ node {Other}}
      }
      child{ node {Western}}}
    child {node {Second-generation}
      child{ node {Western}}
      child{ node {Non-Western}
             child{ node {Turkey}}
        child{ node {Morocco}}
        child{ node {Surinam}}
             child{ node {Netherlands Antilles}}
          child{ node {Other}}}
    }

  ;
  \end{tikzpicture} 

\footnotesize
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
        text width = 2.7cm, text badly centered,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
           anchor = east,
             grow = east,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 1mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 6mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
               }
[Total sample
    [Second generation
        [Non Western
            [Turkey]
            [Morocco]
            [Surinam]
            [Antilles]
            [Other]

        ]
        [Western]
    ]
%
    [Natives, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
%
    [First generation
        [Non Western
            [Turkey]
            [Morocco]
            [Surinam]
            [Antilles]
            [Other]

        ]
        [Western]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At `forest` with adding `for tree` option `tier/.option=level` you will obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
        text width = 27mm, text badly centered,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
           anchor = east,
             grow = east,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 1mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
tier/.option=level
               }
[Total sample
    [Second generation
        [Non Western
            [Turkey]
            [Morocco]
            [Surinam]
            [Antilles]
            [Other]
%
        ]
        [Western]
    ]
%
    [Natives, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
%
    [First generation
        [Non Western
            [Turkey]
            [Morocco]
            [Surinam]
            [Antilles]
            [Other]
%
        ]
        [Western]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Remark, I would reduce nodes width to for example 21mm and get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answered my question!